# Android error: Android Resources$NotFoundException when using custom theme with BottomSheetDialog and custom drawable resource

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, material-design, filenotfoundexception

I'm encountering an issue with a Resources$NotFoundException when using a custom theme along with a BottomSheetDialog and a custom drawable resource. The error message suggests that there is a problem resolving an attribute related to the drawable resource.

I have the following styles defined in my styles.xml file:

```
    <style name="sheetView" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/drawable_bg_rounded_corners_top</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/cardBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/sheetView</item>
        <item name="android:theme">@style/com.android.settings.Theme.Panel</item>
    </style>
```

The issue arises when I try to use the custom theme (AppBottomSheetDialogTheme) with a BottomSheetDialog in my Android settings app. The exact error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.android.settings:drawable/ic_wifi_signal_0 with resource ID #0x7f080952
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040875 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f13059acom.android.settings:style/Theme.Panel, id=0x1030403android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Settings.Dialog, id=0x1030407android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Settings.DialogBase, id=0x1030438android:style/Theme.Material.Light.BaseDialog, id=0x1030237android:style/Theme.Material.Light, id=0x103000candroid:style/Theme.Light, id=0x1030005android:style/Theme]}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:600)
at com.android.settings.widget.TintDrawable.b(TintDrawable.java:4)
at com.android.settings.widget.TintDrawable.applyTheme(TintDrawable.java:4)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:802)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1060)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:1050)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:989)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:810)
at com.android.settings.wifi.addappnetworks.AddAppNetworksFragment$e.getView(AddAppNetworksFragment.java:11)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2414)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1417)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1323)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26653)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7074)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
```

I suspect that the issue is related to the combination of the custom theme, the BottomSheetDialog, and the drawable resource. I have verified that the drawable resource (ic_wifi_signal_0) exists in the com.android.settings package.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully use the custom theme with the BottomSheetDialog without encountering the Resources$NotFoundException.

Note: the issue is only producible in some devices like CPH2411 OnePlus